# MVC5 EF6 with migrations - seeding a membership user

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am setting up my seed methods in my migration's configuration class.

I have added a reference to the following name spaces

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
```

and wrote up the following method that gets called from the Seed method

```
private void SeedMembership(MyDbContext context)
    {

            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = "demo"};
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
            var result = UserManager.Create(user,"demo");


    }
```

The idea was to have this aoto create a user with username=demo and password=demo

but I cant compile getting the following error:

```
using the generic type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<TUser>' requires 1 type argument
```

I am a bit stuck as to why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a typo:

```
var result = UserManager.Create(user,"demo");
```

You should use `userManager`, note the lower-case `u`.